# Take out part of a string that fits a pattern

Tags: r, regex

Currently I have a code like this.

```
Filename <- file.choose()
dirname <- dirname(Filename)
setwd(dirname)
print(dirname)
```

Which gives an output like: “Volumes/Lab/Data/Darwin/Patient1/Cancer/Well1/P3F5/PointMutation”

I want to be able to create a substring of dirname and have it set to “P3F5”, getting rid of everything else. I have other folders like P10H11, and P1D1. I’d would prefer it be through regex as I want this code to be replicable, and the dirname character count won’t always be the same and the Folders change quite a bit with other files due to inconsistent file making (sorry). The only consistent pattern I see is P[number from 1-10][Letter][number from 1-12] to extract the string I want,  and I am at a loss as to how to use regex to be that specific. I have tried

```
sub("(P[0-10][:alpha:][0-12])","\\1", dirname)
```

but it just outputs the same name, so I think I am doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So are you saying you always want the second-to-last entry in the full path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the group using `sub`

```
sub('.*(P[0-9]+[A-Z][0-9]+).*','\\1', dirname)
#[1] "P3F5"
```

---

Some more examples to verify

```
x <- 'Volumes/Lab/Data/Darwin/Patient1/Cancer/Well1/P10Q11/PointMutation'
sub('.*(P[0-9]+[A-Z][0-9]+).*','\\1', x)
#[1] "P10Q11"

x <- 'Volumes/Lab/Data/Darwin/Patient1/Cancer/Well1/P6Q2/PointMutation'
sub('.*(P[0-9]+[A-Z][0-9]+).*','\\1', x)
#[1] "P6Q2"
```

---

A non-regex approach if we want the directory which is always second last use `basename` and `dirname`

```
x <- 'Volumes/Lab/Data/Darwin/Patient1/Cancer/Well1P6Q20/P6Q2/PointMutation'
basename(dirname(x))
#[1] "P6Q2"

x <- 'Volumes/Lab/Data/Darwin/Patient1/Cancer/Well1/P10Q11/PointMutation'
basename(dirname(x))
#[1] "P10Q11"
```

Comment: I think you might want to make this more specific, and insist on file separators on at least one side of the match.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you mean something like this `sub('.*\\/(P[0-9]+[A-Z][0-9]+)\\/.*','\\1', dirname)` ?

Comment: Or make one optional, if the OP could let us know where it might be +1.

Comment: This is great @RonakShah Can you explain what the + sign means in the sub function?

Comment: @DarwinChang If you want to include numbers with two digits you need `+`, otherwise it would only capture numbers with 1 digit. Remove the `+` sign from the regex and run the command for `P10Q11` and `P1Q11` and see the difference in output.

Comment: So the + is able to say "If there is an extra digit, add it as well?" Appreciate the help again, and thanks for the secondary option.